# File keeps reappear every time I delete it CentOS 7

Tags: centos, files, delete

I'm cleaning a directory on the CentOS 7 server over SSH and can't delete one file. It is deleted without errors and reappears with size 0 in a moment after I'm deleting it.

I've tried:

1. rm
2. sudo rm
3. Midnight Commander F8

If I remove directory completely or rename it file disappear. But if directory exists it keeps to resurrect.

Comment: You have a running task that keeps creating it.

Comment: Try running `sudo lsof /path/to/filename`; should give you an idea of what's creating it.

Comment: @ajgringo619, thank you for suggestion, but `sudo lsof /path/to/filename` including or excluding filename gives nothing if I running it from other directory. If I'm in the same directory as file and running it with the path without filename I see `bash`, `sudo` and `lsof`.

Comment: try auditd: [Using auditctl for defining and executing Audit rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/auditing-the-system_security-hardening#using-auditctl-for-defining-and-executing-audit-rules_auditing-the-system). it won't show just instant t, it will record everything over time.

Comment: Thank you, @A.B . But it seems I don't understand how to correctly setup audit. I don't see anything about this file in audit.log. I think I'll leave this issue for a while and return to it later.